# Tomcat Authentication using LDAP with just username and without password

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, jndi

I have a web application which is hosted on apache web server. And i have external java application which runs on tomcat integrated in this web application.

The apache is kerberized and I get the username of the person accessing it in the intranet. I want to use the same username and pass it on tomcat to check against ldap and authorize the user.

I was looking into JNDI realm which supports LDAP module. But the problem is I do not have access to the user's password. But I'm able to get the groups the user belongs to and based on that I want to authenticate the user.

So my question is will i be able to authenticate a user against Tomcat server via LDAP with just the username and not the password?

PS: Sorry there is no code or configuration that I can post at this point. The only resources i found implemented both username and password. I cannot kerberize the tomcat server because I have other issues in the network.

Comment: So authentication consists of 'does this user exist'? In which case your question is can I query LDAP to see if a record exists for this user, to which the answer must be yes. However, your solution sounds very insecure.

Answer (score 0):

> "I was looking into JNDI realm which supports LDAP module. But the problem is I do not have 
>   access to the user's password. But I'm able to get the groups the user belongs to and based 
>   on that I want to authenticate the user."

Once I was asked to write some code to do the very same thing.  I found a way to make it work.  However, although it seemed to work well enough with Internet Explorer which would automatically detect the Windows username (because my code was parsing some NTLM information that only Internet Explorer passes in as a header), in Firefox or any other browser the user would be presented with an authentication box and any username they typed in would be accepted!  Its very insecure.

(Well, its not really true that only IE passes the header in.  Only IE passes it in automatically; but Firefox also passes it in after someone gets the authentication box and types in any name they want.  That's the problem.)

What I would suggest is writing a C#.NET service to do the authentication for real on a webserver that is IIS and has Integrated Authentication on.  Then, redirect to the C# service when someone hits the Java site and the username session variable is null. Have the C# service save the info in a trusted/secure database including ip address and browser and redirect to the Java app which reads the db to validate IP address and browser and that the record was just created.

Edit: I just noticed you said your Apache is kerberized and already gets the Windows username, which may render the problem above about the unreliability of parsing the NTLM header null and void.  In this case, if you can get the AD groups via LDAP you can authenticate the user in your webapp with your own code, but probably not using the official Tomcat authentication scheme. What is described above is just because my Tomcat is not paired with an Apache server but with a IIS server.  So basically, its the same thing, except you won't need C#.

Comment: Your solution sounds more like having a middle layer between my apache application and tomcat application. This would work great if the only way they could go through was my apache web application. However, if the user did get the link to the tomcat application (which he could using firebug, chrome tools) there would be no tomcat authentication and this would defeat the whole purpose.